# Shift contents of array using parameters in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, parameters, shift

I have been playing around with a bit of code for the past few weeks. The code is a display of the number 1. I want to essentially create a dot matrix style print out, where the 1 is continuously shifted to the right.
Here is where I am so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* use function to shift all characters one place to the right */
/* use a function to declare the characters of the fiqure */
int i, j;
int matrix([int i][int j]);//dont think this is right
```

I have declared my variables, and the matrix with the parameters I and j

```
int main()
{
    //should the matrix be a global function, therefore can be accessed by the move function?
    /* the matrix is contained within the matrix function. The goal of main, is to manipulate
    the matrix to transponse the elements to the next column*/

    // 8 rows and 13 columns 

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int p = (j + 3)%13;
        for (j = p; j < 13 ; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j + 3];
            //priting out the matrix 
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int matrix(int i, int j)
/* this function sets up the matrix and returns the value of the matrix. 
this function should simply be a display function */
{
    int matrix[8][13] = { { 0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } };

    //display the elements
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            //priting out the matrix 
            cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return matrix[i][j];
}
```

Here is the main function, where I attempt to assign actual parameters for the matrix and pass them to the matrix display. The main function specifically defines a variable ‘p’ which (the plan is anyway) to use this variable to cause a shift to the right. 
I am using the modulo 13 operator to attempt to clear (or return to 0) values after the shift, so the 1 appears to move across the matrix

In addition to the functions above, I have included the last bits from my code which are essentially notes and ideas that I am attempting now.

```
/*
int array_size = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (j = array_size-1; j > 0; j--)
        {
            matrix[j] = matrix[j - 1];
        }
        matrix[0]=
        cout << "\n";
    }
}


*/

/*
int x = i;
    int p = (j + 3) % 13;
        int matrix(x, p);
    return 0;
*/
```

thanks in advance for any help or guidance :)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: A debugger is your best friend. Programming is not magic, with the debugger you can see what is actually happening during each execution step, and it eliminates the need to ask questions like this one. I'll give you one hint though: matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j + 3]; //why + 3??? j goes from p to 12 and then you add 3, which will exceed the max allowed index which is 12

Comment: Namespace std is not suggested to be used